# Concatenación en python: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, cast

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

ventana = Tk()

ventana.wm_title("Devueltas")
ventana.minsize(width=30, height=20)


lblC = Label(ventana, text="Cantidad a devolver").grid(row=0)
txtC = Entry(ventana, width=10)
txtC.grid(row=0, column=1)


#---------------------------------------------------------
Devueltas = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


def devolver():
    if unicode(txtC.get()).isnumeric:
        cantidad = int(txtC.get())
        P = 0
        while P <= 9:
            if P == 0:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 50000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (50000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 1:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 20000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (20000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 2:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 10000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (10000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 3:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 5000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (5000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 4:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 20000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (2000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 5:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 1000)
                cantidad = cantidad - (1000 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 6:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 500)
                cantidad = cantidad - (500 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 7:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 200)
                cantidad = cantidad - (200 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 8:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 100)
                cantidad = cantidad - (100 * int(Devueltas[P]))
            if P == 9:
                Devueltas[P] = int(cantidad / 50)
                cantidad = cantidad - (50 * int(Devueltas[P]))

            P += 1

        P = 0

        while P <= 9:
            if P == 0:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 50.000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 50.000"
            if P == 1:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 20.000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 20.000"
            if P == 2:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 10.000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 10.000"
            if P == 3:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 5.000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 5.000"
            if P == 4:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 2.000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 2.000"
            if P == 5:
                if Devueltas[P] > 1:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billetes de $ 1000"
                else:
                    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 1000"

            if P == 6:
                Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Moneda de $ 500"

            if P == 7:
                Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Moneda de $ 200"

            if P == 8:
                Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Moneda de $ 100"

            if P == 9:
                Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Moneda de $ 50"

            P += 1
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Devueltas", P)


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
btnCalcular = Button(ventana, text="Devuelta", command=devolver).grid(row=1)

ventana.mainloop()
```

al intentar correr el programa me dice:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Final vector (1).py", line 70, in devolver
    Devueltas[P] = int(Devueltas[P]) + " Billete de $ 50.000"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

¿Qué hago?

Comment: Disculpa, no se python, pero te recomiendo que coloques algún indicio del problema que tienes, así de esa manera si alguien lo sabe pues te ayudara mas rapido

Answer (score 4):

En python los errores están bastante bien explicados

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Esto significa que no podes sumar un entero con una cadena, o concatenar un entero a una cadena como lo estas intentando hacer.

Lo ideal sería:

```
» print str(1) + " Hola mundo"
»"1 Hola mundo"
```